# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap. even with '=='

Tags: angular, migration, equality, angular10

i am migrating my app from Angular 5 tp 10, post migration i am getting error  ***This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.*** even though inside the code we have used ==  not === , should i be aware of some new configuration or feature of angular 10

its already making no sense

i know i can add single quotes on my number but what is the logic that == behaves like === in html/template.

why there was no error in angular 5 ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Angular 10 uses [Ivy AoT](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) for compilation. It mandates the type conformations (incl. in template) in compile time compared to old engine that was JiT.

Ivy just informed you that the conditions have been erroneous from the beginning. If the `roleId` is of type `string` then it should be compared with type `string` instead of a number.

```
roleId == '2'
```

When attempting `roleId == 2`, you're depending on Javascript's [`ToNumber`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) to do a implicit conversion of `roleId` to a number. More details about the abstract equality comparison [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison). This doesn't play well when using Ivy with Typescript.